# Can I open print window in same tab? Datatable

Tags: jquery, printing, datatable

i have table and made datatable on it,

when i click on the print button, it opens a new window 'blank' and print the table !

issue,Any hint to avoid open a new tab ?

Comment: Looks like you've [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232088/avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing-in-datatable). I don't think that option is currently available. You'd need to modify the code. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons/issues/23).

Comment: @showdev This question is not a duplicate. That question is regarding extra blank page in the printout. This question is regarding why the print preview open in a new browser tab.

Comment: The datatable creates a new page/tab to recreate the whole table all by itself and then calls the Print method on that page. So technically you are not printing your current web page that has datatable. You are printing that intermediate page that has only the datatable.

Comment: @NawedKhan The title does seem different, but "How to prevent print button with datatable to open another tab? And print the table in the same page not in new tab!" sounds the same to me. Also, the OP acknowledged having posted a second question because an answer was not yet received on the first one. That comment has since been removed. Please vote to reopen if you feel it's appropriate.

Comment: @showdev you are right, I agree. Duplicate it is!